# Trying to pass objects to an array and then search the array to return the object

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to create a program that will allow me to enter object information to an array and then search that array for pieces of the object and return the object.

At this point I'm not sure if my objects are being put in to the array and if my calls are correct.

Ideally I want to populate the array of objects, then when the menu displays choose a search option. I will search the array of objects for a match and display the object(s) to that match.

I'm not sure where my mistake is as this is not returning my search options. Assistance finding it would be great. Thank you!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Greeting();
        WriteLine();
        School [] newStudent = new School[4];
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string major;
        int id;
        double gpa;
        for (int i = 0; i < newStudent.Length; i++)
        {
            GetInfo(out firstName, out lastName, out major);
            id = GetId();
            gpa = GetGpa();
            WriteLine();
            newStudent[i] = new School(lastName, firstName, major, id, gpa);
        }
        DisplayMenu();
        int menuOpt = GetChoice();
        DoChoice(menuOpt, newStudent);


    }

    static void Greeting()
    {
        WriteLine("Student Input");
    }

    static void GetInfo(out string lastn, out string firstn, out string mjr)
    {
        Write("Enter student's last name: ");
        lastn = ReadLine();
        Write("Enter student's first name: ");
        firstn = ReadLine();
        Write("Enter student's major: ");
        mjr = ReadLine();
    }

    static int GetId()
    {
        Write("Enter student's ID number: ");
        int inum = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        while (inum <= 0)
        {
            Write("ID number must be greater than 0. Please enter student's ID number: ");
            inum = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        }
        return inum;
    }

    static double GetGpa()
    {
        Write("Enter student's GPA: ");
        double sgpa = double.Parse(ReadLine());
        while (sgpa < 0.0 || sgpa > 4.0)
        {
            Write("That's not a valid GPA. Try Again: ");
            sgpa = double.Parse(ReadLine());
        }
        return sgpa;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        WriteLine("1. Search by Last Name");
        WriteLine("2. Search by First Name");
        WriteLine("3. Search by Major");
        WriteLine("4. Quit");
    }

    static int GetChoice()
    {
        Write("What is your choice? ");
        int select = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        while (select < 1 || select > 4)
        {
            Write("That's not a valid choice. Try Again: ");
            select = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        }
        return select;
    }

    static void DoChoice(int choice, params School [] nStudent)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                FindLastName(nStudent);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            //more options will go here at a later date with their matching methods like case 1

        }
    }

    static void FindLastName(params School [] findLName)
    {
        Write("What is the last name? ");
        string findL = ReadLine();
        int pos = Array.IndexOf(findLName, findL);
        if (pos > -1)
        {
            PrintStudent(findLName[pos]);
        }
        else
        {
            Write("No results found with that last name {0}.", findL);
        }
    }

    static void PrintStudent(School student1)
    {
        Write(student1.ToString());
    }
```

---

```
 class School
{
    private string lname;
    private string fname;
    private double gpa;
    private string major;
    private int id;

    public School (string ln, string fn, string maj, int ident, double grade)
    {
        lname = ln;
        fname = fn;
        major = maj;
        id = ident;
        gpa = grade;
    }

    public string Lname
    {
        get
        {
            return lname;
        }
        set
        {
            lname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Fname
    {
        get
        {
            return fname;
        }
        set
        {
            fname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Major
    {
        get
        {
            return major;
        }
        set
        {
            major = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string student = lname + ", " + fname + "; " + id + " " + major + " " + gpa.ToString("D2");
        return student;
    }
```

UPDATE!: So I have confirmed that my array is populating my objects, however I'm wondering if those values are being passed properly to my methods.
Currently trying to search the array of objects with my FindLastName() method is only returning the else statement as if the values in the array do not exist.

UPDATE 2: After making some suggested changes, I'm about 80% confident my error lies within this method.

```
static void FindLastName(params School [] findLName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < findLName.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine(findLName[i]);

        }
        // The above loop proves that the objects exist within the array after being passed to the method.

        Write("What is the last name? ");
        string findL = ReadLine();
        School foundStudent = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < findLName.Length; i++)
        {
            if (findLName[i].Lname == findL)
            {
                foundStudent = findLName[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundStudent != null)
        {
            PrintStudent(foundStudent);
        }
        else
        {
            Write("No results found with that last name {0}.", findL);
        }
        // When I run this it returns the else statement even though I am using a last name that exists within the array
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question or do you just want to get a review on your code? But I wouldn't work with the index of the full name, because you assume that the user has entered the full name - is your question how you could improve that search part of your code?

Comment: Currently when I search my array nothing is populating, so I think either my search method is wrong or my objects are not populating. So my question is where is my mistake AND a review would be great as well.

Comment: You didn't show the constructor for `School`, but presumably the arguments that are passed to it are used to set the properties of the object?

Comment: Apologies. I have added in the class.

Comment: Might I suggest you step through your code with a debugger and have a look at the contents of your array directly. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the way you populate your array, however, I would suggest that you use a List<School> rather than an array given that you will probably be dealing with an indeterminate number of items. However, I could be wrong here. Also, you might want to rephrase your question such that you're not asking for "feedback" but a specific question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just add `Console.WriteLine(newStudent[i])` inside the for loop where you populate your array and that will show you whether or not you've created the objects and populated the array successfully.

Comment: @JamesHughes Whenever I try to use that I get a runtime-error saying that there is something wrong with my ToString() method. Any thoughts?

Comment: “Whenever I try to use something I'm not showing you I get a runtime-error I'm not showing you. Any thoughts?” Yes, show us what you're using and the runtime error it gives you.

Comment: @DourHighArch I have resolved the runtime error. Currently the program is working, but my logic is wrong. I have confirmed the array of objects is populating, but I cannot get my search method to search the data, find, and print properly.

Comment: See my answer, I'm not sure if it helps you entirely but it's a pretty solid way of making searches easy in general. If you need more explanation or help just let me know.

Comment: @JamesHughes I have to use an array for this, otherwise I'd be happy to make it as easy as possible :)

Comment: @ZynVak, fair, apart from the comment at the end, my answer is designed to work with an array. Might I also suggest that `Student` might be a more appropriate name for the class unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @JamesHughes No, I just gave it a generic name when I started with it. School was the first thing that came to mind. But thank you so very much for all your input!

Comment: Fair enough, I hope you've had your issue resolved, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are passing the parameters to `GetInfo()` in the wrong order, which ends up swapping the person's first name with their last name. So then later, when you're searching for someone by their last name, you will never get a match!

The function signature looks like this (with `lastName` as the FIRST argument):

```
static void GetInfo(out string lastn, out string firstn, out string mjr)
```

But you are calling it like this (with `lastName` as the SECOND argument):

```
GetInfo(out firstName, out lastName, out major);
```

So to resolve this issue, you just need to swap the positions of `firstName` and `lastName` in the line above.

Also, I just noticed that you are trying to format the GPA as a date, which will not work. You might consider changing this line:

```
gpa.ToString("D2")
```

to this (if you want to show one decimal place):

```
gpa.ToString("0.0")
```

Comment: Ok perfect! I can't believe I was missing that piece! Only issue with this is it only returns the iteration of that last name, so if I have multiple people with the same last night I need to be able to display them all. Also I have fixed the ToString() issues :)

Comment: I'll update my other answer so that it will print out everyone whos name is a match

Answer (score 0):

Based on the concepts it looks like you've learned so far, you probably want to change your logic a little bit in your search algorithm.

1. What you can do is create a Boolean variable to track whether or not you found any students, and start it off with `false`
2. Then loop through your array, one student at a time, and compare the last name to the one we're searching for
3. If we find the student, output their details and set our Boolean variable to `true`.
4. Outside of the loop, we can now just check to see if our variable is false, and if it is we can write the message that no students were found:

The reason using `IndexOf` wasn't working like you wanted it to is that you have to pass an object of the type stored in the array, and it has to be an exact match to one in the array (the `Compare` method of the class would return true).

...

```
static void FindLastName(params School[] findLName)
{
    Write("What is the last name? ");
    string findL = ReadLine();

    // Create a variable to track if we find a match
    bool foundStudent = false;

    // Search through each array item
    for (int i = 0; i < findLName.Length; i++)
    {
        // See if this item's last name is a match
        if (findLName[i].LName == findL)
        {
            // If it is, set our variable to this student and break out of the for loop
            PrintStudent(findLName[i]);
            foundStudent = true;
        }
    }

    // If our variable is false (or "not true" in the syntax here), we tell the user
    if (!foundStudent)
    {
        Write("No results found with that last name {0}.", findL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had something similar to this the first time I wrote this and it's going right to the else statement, as if the objects are not populating in to the array, so that's why I ended up trying to see if the IndexOf() worked. Thoughts?

Comment: Updated answer to write output for all matching students

Comment: Thank you so very much! Everything has helped clear up these concepts as well as remind me to slow down and make sure I'm paying attention when coding. I could have saved myself a lot of time to begin with had I practiced such things. Thanks again so very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise LINQ to make this search nice and easy with something like this:

```
string searchValue = PutSearchValueInHere();
School[] selectedStudentArray = schoolArray.Where(school=>school.SearchField == searchValue).ToArray();
School selectedStudent = selectedStudentArray[0]; //Assuming you used a primary key as your search field
```

Essentially how this works is you pick a field (likely a unique student ID) and a property of your class (eg `.StudentID`) then pass it into the extention method `.Where` of your array as a lambda expression. It will then return any items where the lambda evaluates to `true`.

The expression `school=>school.SearchField == searchValue` essentially means "Does the search value equal the SearchField of this school object, yes/no?" and it repeats this operation for every item in your array.

Next, the `.ToArray()` simply tells it to store the results as a new array.

After you've done this, assuming only one student fits the criteria, you are free to select the first item in the array. However, it might be worth checking to see if this is empty or not.

As an after-thought, I really can't help but feel that you should be storing student information in a SQL database and accessing it through an ODBC link, but that's something different entirely.